# is it worth it to use hlsl shaders for 2D drawing

Tags: xna, 2d, shader, hlsl

I was wondering if it is worth it to use shaders to draw a 2D texture in xna. I am asking because with openGL it is much faster if you use GLSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Everything on a modern GPU is drawn using a shader.**

For the old immediate-style rendering (ie: `glBegin`/`glVertex`), that will get converted to something approximating buffers and shaders somewhere in the driver. This is why using GLSL is "faster" - because it's closer to the metal, you're not going through a conversion layer.

For a modern API, like XNA, everything is already built around "buffers and shaders".

---

In XNA, `SpriteBatch` provides its own shader. The source code for the shader is [available here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/stock_effects). The shader itself is *very* simple: The vertex shader is a single matrix multiplication to transform the vertices to the correct raster locations. The pixel shader simply samples from your sprite's texture.

You can't really do much to make `SpriteBatch`'s shader faster - there's almost nothing to it. There are some things you can do to make the buffering behaviour faster in specific circumstances (for example: if your sprites don't change between frames) - but this is kind of advanced. If you're experiencing performance issues with `SpriteBatch`, be sure you're [using it properly in the first place](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9289/288). For what it does, `SpriteBatch` is already extremely well optimised.

For more info on optimisation, see [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/37794/288).

---

If you want to pass a *custom* shader into `SpriteBatch` (eg: for a special effect) use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433700.aspx) overload of `Begin` and pass in an appropriate `Effect`.